# How to extract datatype columns without dtype function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Currently i am using dtype function  to extract the datatype of each each columns.i am trying to extract the data type without using dtype function And create a result in the dict with key as column name and value as datatype.

```
Example 
Import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel(file,dtype=object)
```

I am loading each data as string because data have some Nan value as well as #N/A value so pandas auto convert int to float so to prevent this conversion i am loading as object.

```
Expected output format with sample data.

A   B   C   D   E         f
1.0 3  Nan ram  1-09-2019 2
2.0 4  roh raj  2-08-2020 3
NaN 3.0 ro rax  3/09/2020 4

Result :
{'A':'float','B':'float','C':'string','D':'string','E':'datetime','f':'int'}
```

Can any give suggestion or example how i  with this expected output without using dtype function.

Comment: Could you clarify please? Don't you want the first to columns in your expected result to be 'int'?

Pandas has a pd.to_numeric() function that allows you to downcast any numerical column to float/int, and pd.to_datetime() for object columns that contains dates. Furthermore, you can specify the dtype per column when using read_csv(). Wouldn't that solve your issues?

Comment: @flow_me_over1 i already tried all this then i am switching out of all these.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import everything as string and then try to reinvent to wheel. Instead let pandas infer the datatypes at import and then [convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes) the columns to the best possible type (date columns have to be converted explicitely or you indicate them at import).

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s="""A   B   C   D   E         f
1.0 3  Nan ram  1-09-2019 2
2.0 4  roh raj  2-08-2020 3
NaN 3.0 ro rax  3/09/2020 4"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s+')
df.E = pd.to_datetime(df.E)
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

Result:

```
      A  B    C    D          E  f
0     1  3  Nan  ram 2019-01-09  2
1     2  4  roh  raj 2020-02-08  3
2  <NA>  3   ro  rax 2020-03-09  4
```

`df.dtypes()`:

```
A             Int64
B             Int64
C            string
D            string
E    datetime64[ns]
f             Int64
```